# I want to automate tradingview with capitalise.ai

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to automate tradingview with capitalise.ai.

Now I get 2 signals for each candle, but I only want to get 1 signal if it is at a SellSignal or if it is at a BuySignal.

Can this be solved?

```
//@version=5
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true)

//HMA
len6 = 125
src6 = close
hma = ta.wma(2 * ta.wma(src6, len6 / 2) - ta.wma(src6, len6), math.floor(math.sqrt(len6)))
hmacolor = close > hma ? #00ccff : #ff0055
plot(hma, title='HMA Line', color=color.new(hmacolor, 25), linewidth=5)

//Condition    
if (hmacolor == #00ccff and hmacolor[1] != #00ccff)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
if (hmacolor == #ff0055 and hmacolor[1] != #ff0055)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)

//Alert
ttbuystring = 'Input your custom alert message here.'
ttsellstring = 'Input your custom alert message here.'
ttstopstring = 'Input your custom alert message here.'
usebuyalert = input.bool(defval=true, title='Use BUY Alert', group='Alert Messages')
buystring = input.string(title='Buy Alert Message', defval='BUY', confirm=false, group='Alert Messages', tooltip=ttbuystring)
usesellalert = input.bool(defval=true, title='Use SELL Alert', group='Alert Messages')
sellstring = input.string(title='Sell Alert Message', defval='SELL', confirm=false, group='Alert Messages', tooltip=ttsellstring)

if usebuyalert
    alert(buystring, alert.freq_once_per_bar)
if usesellalert
    alert(sellstring, alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//@version=5
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true)

//HMA
len6 = 125
src6 = close
hma = ta.wma(2 * ta.wma(src6, len6 / 2) - ta.wma(src6, len6), math.floor(math.sqrt(len6)))
hmacolor = close > hma ? #00ccff : #ff0055
plot(hma, title='HMA Line', color=color.new(hmacolor, 25), linewidth=5)

//Variables for alerts
ttbuystring = 'Input your custom alert message here.'
ttsellstring = 'Input your custom alert message here.'
ttstopstring = 'Input your custom alert message here.'
usebuyalert = input.bool(defval=true, title='Use BUY Alert', group='Alert Messages')
buystring = input.string(title='Buy Alert Message', defval='BUY', confirm=false, group='Alert Messages', tooltip=ttbuystring)
usesellalert = input.bool(defval=true, title='Use SELL Alert', group='Alert Messages')
sellstring = input.string(title='Sell Alert Message', defval='SELL', confirm=false, group='Alert Messages', tooltip=ttsellstring)

//Condition    
if (hmacolor == #00ccff and hmacolor[1] != #00ccff) and strategy.position_size < 0
    strategy.close("Short")

if (hmacolor == #ff0055 and hmacolor[1] != #ff0055) and strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.close("Long")

if (hmacolor == #00ccff and hmacolor[1] != #00ccff) and strategy.position_size <= 0
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    if usebuyalert
        alert(buystring, alert.freq_once_per_bar)

if (hmacolor == #ff0055 and hmacolor[1] != #ff0055) and strategy.position_size >= 0
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
    if usesellalert
        alert(sellstring, alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

Comment: The “alert() function calls only” Alert type, are still giving me 1 buy and 1 sell signal in every minutes. (on the 1 minute chart) Maybe the error is in the alert section. this short video is expleaning how to add Alerts, but we need a script to do it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ccqW-GYx88E

Comment: ok, I had not checked the alerts section. I will check it now

Comment: Updated the coded for alerts too. Please take a look

Comment: You could also add the alert in the strategy.entry line ==> Syntax ==>  strategy.entry(id, direction, qty, limit, stop, oca_name, oca_type, comment, alert_message)

Comment: Please let me test it for a couple of hours, it looks like it will be perfect. :) I VERY GRATEFULLY THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP!